# Nested weights warning

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, warnings

I get this warning on my layout in Android Studio:

> Nested weights are bad for performance less...
>  Layout weights require
>   a widget to be measured twice. When a LinearLayout with non-zero
>   weights is nested inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights,
>   then the number of measurements increase exponentially. 
> Issue id:
>   NestedWeights

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#093A3E"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="One"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3AAFB9"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="Two"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#64E9EE"
            android:text="Three"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#97C8EB"
            android:text="Four"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

How can I avoid this warning and get the same result? Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry. Only 2 levels deep is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For better approach i posted the code below using ConstraintLayout***

For your approach here is the solution
Remove from layouts  `android:layout_weight="1"`

You should have reformat your code in the following order.

1. LinearLayout (root) orientation vertical (containing 2 other LinearLayouts)
2. LinearLayout (top, inside root) orientation horizontal ( with button weights to 1)
3. LinearLayout (bottom,inside root) orientation horizontal( with button weights to 1)

**Better approach would be Using ConstraintLayout**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```